# Accessing arrays in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i am new to javascript and as i know you can access an array item that is an object with this syntax `arrayName[index].property`
now consider this example:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    required: true,
    type: String,
    minlength: 1,
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
    validate: {
      validator: validator.isEmail,
      message: "{VALUE} is not a valid email"
    }
  },
  password: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 6,
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  tokens: [
    {
      access: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      token: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

if i try to access the token property in the tokens array like this `"tokens.token"` mongoose let me do it. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you can do this with Mongoose is that this is valid MongoDB query syntax (rather than standard JavaScript) for querying an object property within an array field.

This is also why you need to have the quotes: `"tokens.token"`

So the following query will find all documents where the **token** property of any object in the **tokens** array matches the string **"something"**:

```
Model.find({ "tokens.token": "something" }, function(err, docs) {
  // Do something with result
})
```